# How to achieve Log in functionality without Session Or If I use a Session then How to solve frequent Logout

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, session-state

I am using session state variable for login purpose in my application.
 I am facing very much problem of frequently session  gets expired.

Major Problem is If I closed the winow of browser without log out & if I have visited again the same page I Should automatically login & session should not be expired.

What Should I do to resolve this problem.

Should I use the session state for log in ????

Will that be helpful for me?????????????

Like Gmail If we close the window of the browser without log out then If we again go to gmail.com you did not have to again login

How will that be possible in asp.net

Comment: how to write a cookie

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the Session to store login information.

Have you looked at using Microsoft Membership for your authentication requirements?  Take a look at this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Hardik, here is a Walkthrough that takes you throught the process of using Membership Step By Step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx